# How to implement 'sqlite3_busy_timeout' in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite

I'm trying to run a python script with multiple threads, but I'm getting the following error:

sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

I've found out that I need to extend the sqlite3_busy_timeout to make it wait a bit longer before writing to the database.

The code used for this looks like the following:

'db.configure("busyTimeout", 10000)' //This should make it wait for 10 seconds.

What I want to know is how do I implement this code? Where should I place it, before or after the SQLite command? also, do I have to write anything before it? like c.execute("code")?

Comment: SQLite really isn't well-suited to multiple writers. The timeout for database locks is defined [on the connection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) but... the default is already 5 seconds (longer than you want to set it to). A single writer and multiple readers, with Write-Ahead Logging would be fine, but not multiple writers.

Comment: I have edited it now to 10 seconds. I want to see if it helps.

Comment: Well my comment already explained how to do it, so you can try it and see. But it's not going to be a particularly stable system if you're already getting concurrency issues with the 5 second timeout. You're using the wrong tool for your task.

Comment: You're right, SQLite may not be the right choise for this application. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timeout with the [busy_timeout pragma](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout). Here is an example setting the busy timeout to 10 seconds:

```py
import sqlite3
with sqlite3.connect('example.db') as db
    db.execute('pragma busy_timeout=10000') 
    # do more work with db...
```